# Is menu_set_active_trail the way to go if I need to change user/* page titles?

Tags: 7

I've had the pleasure of spending a bit of time trying to change the page titles (the one you get via `drupal_get_title()`) of `user`, `user/register` and `user/password`. It appears that this is doable in a not so consistent manner by either :

1. Invoke `drupal_set_title` from e.g. `hook_form_user_register_form_alter`, but as this form may be added to any other page which already has a title I assume this may come with undesired side effects.
2. ...or change `$vars['title']` in a preprocess function, but this doesn't really change the page title. It just changes the `$title` variable which is injected into the template. Other modules (e.g. metatag) would still use the default title.
3. ...or use `hook_menu_alter` to set do `$items['user']['title callback'] = 'user_title';`, and from there set the page title via `function user_title`. It seems, however, that this does not work as long as there is a menu item in *some* menu that links to `user`. In that case, the `user` page will be given the title of the menu item of the most preferred menu :

[menu.inc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_set_active_trail/7.x):

```
    // Try to retrieve a menu link corresponding to the current path. If more
    // than one exists, the link from the most preferred menu is returned.
    $preferred_link = menu_link_get_preferred();
    $current_item = menu_get_item();
```

4. ...or use `hook_init` to invoke `menu_set_active_trail` from there. This ensures that the active trail is set, and thus that's the trail which will be used unless other modules explicitly invoke `menu_set_active_trail_again`. The drawback with this one is that some modules (e.g. the user module) will invoke `menu_set_active_item` and `menu_execute_active_handler` again - and thus setting a custom page title in this case fails.

Number *1* and *2* is either flawed or has side effects. While *3* seemed to be the way to go it appears that any menu item which links to the current path will override any title which otherwise would be set by the `title callback`. Number *4* works most of the time, but not when you go to `user` as a logged in user.

So, I've now implemented `hook_menu_site_status` to (1) check which path the user is attempting to access and (2) from there invoke `menu_set_active_trail` with a custom trail so that I override any trail generated by Drupal based on existing menu items (#3 above). This works even if a module calls `menu_execute_active_handler` again.

*Now, although this works, it feels a bit "brute force"-ish. Is this really the way to change a page title when a menu item links to the same page and thus apparently has the last word on what a page title should be?*. It feels very convoluted.

Comment: I would have done #1 and using [get_current_path()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/current_path/7.x) to check the path; thus, preventing the side effect.